# how to pass bucket/key name to fargate job via a cloudwatch event trigger on s3 object creation event?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-fargate

I have create a fargate task and trying to trigger it via s3 object creation event ( see sample below) via cloudformation.as it cannot trigger it directly, i have created a cloudwatchevent.  I am trying to pass the bucket and obj name to my fargate task code . doing some research, i came across ->  InputTransformer, but i'm not sure how to pass the value of my bucket and key name and how to read it in my python code. any help will be appreciated.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: An example CloudFormation template for Fargate.
Parameters:
  VPC:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC::Id
  SubnetA:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id
  SubnetB:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id
  Image:
    Type: String
    Default: 123456789012.dkr.ecr.region.amazonaws.com/image:tag
Resources:
  mybucket:
    Properties:
      BucketName: 'mytestbucket-us'

  cloudwatchEvent:
    Type: AWS::Events::Rule
    Properties:
      EventPattern:
        source: 
          - aws.s3
        detail:
          eventSource: 
            - s3.amazonaws.com
          eventName: 
            - PutObject
            - CompleteMultipartUpload
          requestParameters:
            bucketName:
              - !Ref mybucket
    Targets:
      - Id: my-fargate-task
        Arn: myclusterArn
        RoleArn: myinvocationrolearn
        Input:
          'Fn::Sub':
             - >-
               {"containerOverrides": [{"name":"somecontainer"]}
        EcsParameters:
          TaskDefinition:
            LaunchType: 'FARGATE'
            ...
          NetworkConfiguration:
            ...
  
  Cluster:
    Type: AWS::ECS::Cluster
    Properties:
      ClusterName: !Join ['', [!Ref ServiceName, Cluster]]

  TaskDefinition:
    Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
    DependsOn: LogGroup
    Properties:
      Family: !Join ['', [!Ref ServiceName, TaskDefinition]]
      NetworkMode: awsvpc
      RequiresCompatibilities:
        - FARGATE
      Cpu: 256
      Memory: 2GB
      ExecutionRoleArn: !Ref ExecutionRole
      TaskRoleArn: !Ref TaskRole
      ContainerDefinitions:
        - Name: !Ref ServiceName
          Image: !Ref Image

  # A role needed by ECS
  ExecutionRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: !Join ['', [!Ref ServiceName, ExecutionRole]]
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com
            Action: 'sts:AssumeRole'
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - 'arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy'
  # A role for the containers
  TaskRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: !Join ['', [!Ref ServiceName, TaskRole]]
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com
            Action: 'sts:AssumeRole'
```

Answer (score 2):

You would use a [CloudWatch Event Input Transformer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/CloudWatch-Events-Input-Transformer-Tutorial.html) to extract the data you need from the event, and pass that data to the ECS task as environment variable(s) in the target's `ContainerOverrides`. I don't use CloudFormation, but [here's an example using Terraform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62845436/how-to-use-input-transformer-for-ecs-fargate-launch-type-with-terraform-cloudwat).

Comment: thanks. I deployed everything via cloudformation, but when i upload a file to my bucket , it doesn't trigger the fargate job. I have tested this with a time based rule and the job gets triggered but when i switch to this cloudwatch event tied to ojbect creation in s3 , it doesn't work. I have updated my question with other details , can you take a look at my template and see if i'm missing anything , permissions ...e.t.c

Comment: @ozil did you enable S3 events in EventBridge? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/enable-event-notifications-eventbridge.html

Comment: Yes, it looks like there is an EventBridge configuration available: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-bucket-notificationconfig.html

Comment: does the cloudwatch event needs access/permissions to be able to start the fargate job. if yes, how do i attach a policy to the cloudwatch event rule

Comment: Yes it needs the appropriate permissions to invoke the ECS task. You attach the role via the Event Rule Target `RoleArn` property https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-events-rule-target.html

Comment: i added a role with policy - AmazonEc2ContainerServiceEventsRole. but still no luck. I am going to try to invoke a lambda and then invoke the fargate job. this should be fairly straightforward , i think

Comment: You added that role to the EventBridge trigger?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. CloudWatch events **do not pass** data to ECS jobs. You need to develop your own mechanism for that. For example, trigger lambda first, store event in S3 Parameter Store or DynamoDB, and then invoke your ECS job which will get stored data.

Comment: Not true, you can do this via the CloudWatch Events input transformer, and the ECS task's container overrides. See my answer.